# Why influx performance is so slow

Tags: python, mysql, csv, influxdb

I am storing some data in influx and it is quite confusing that influx is 4-5 times slow as Mysql. I try to test by inserting 10000 rows in mysql and then in influxdb. 
and the stats are below.

```
Mysql

real: 6m 39sec
user: 2.956sec  
sys: 0.504sec

Influxdb

real: 6m 17.193sec
user: 11.860sec
sys: 0.328sec
```

my code for influx is given below, I used the same pattern to store in mysql.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import time
import csv
import sys
import datetime
import calendar
import pytz
from influxdb import client as influxdb
from datetime import datetime

host = 'localhost'
port = 8086
user = "admin"
password = "admin"
db_name = "testdatabase"
db = influxdb.InfluxDBClient(database=db_name)


def read_data():
    with open(file) as f:
        reader = f.readlines()[4:]
       for line in reader:
            yield (line.strip().split(','))


fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
file = '/home/rob/mycsvfile.csv'

csvToInflux = read_data()
body = []
for metric in csvToInflux:
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(metric[0][1: len(metric[0]) - 1], fmt)

    new_value = float(metric[1])
    body.append({
        'measurement': 'mytable1',
        'time': timestamp,
        'fields': {
             'col1': metric[1],
             'col2': metric[2],
             'col3': metric[3],
             'col4': metric[4],
             'col5': metric[5],
             'col6': metric[6],
             'col7': metric[7],
             'col8': metric[8],
             'col9': metric[9]
        }
        })
    db.write_points(body)
```

Can someone give me an idea how can I improve it. I think it might be due to cache. is cache option is off by default in Influx db? and can someone guide me to do batch processing in influx. I try to look over SO and google but couldn't solve my problem. I am newbie to influx db. I am trying to make it faster. 
Thanks for any help or tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting one by one into influxdb is slow, you should do it in batches. For example, trying with a CSV of 10000 lines (one by one):

```
with open('/tmp/blah.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

import influxdb

inf = influxdb.InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example1')

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(',')
    json_body = [{
        'measurement': 'one_by_one',
        'time': parts[0],
        'fields':{
            'my_value': int(parts[1].strip())
        }
    }]
    inf.write_points(json_body)
```

This gives me a result of

```
└─ $ ▶ time python influx_one.py

real    1m43.655s
user    0m19.547s
sys     0m3.266s
```

And doing a small change to insert all the lines of the CSV in one go:

```
json_body = []
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(',')
    json_body.append({
        'measurement': 'one_batch',
        'time': parts[0],
        'fields':{
            'my_value': int(parts[1].strip())
        }
    })

inf.write_points(json_body)
```

The result is much much better:

```
└─ $ ▶ time python influx_good.py

real    0m2.693s
user    0m1.797s
sys     0m0.734s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will try it and will come back to update.

Comment: Can you edit my code accordingly because I try to use the batch idea from last example of yours by using json_body and append but it couldn't work for me. thanks a lot

Comment: I can't edit it now (I am with the phone) but why is it not working for you? Do you get an error or is it still slow? @rob

Comment: it is working but still the same, mean still it is too slow. i will make the change in my question according to your suggestion. and will let you know in a moment.

Comment: @ i edit my question and i include the batch process try, but not sure whether done it correctly or not. if i done it correctly then still it is same as previous, mean very slow.

Comment: it works perfectly fine in batch processing. but why is too slow when doing line by line for influxdb and not for mysql?

Comment: Can't tell, I don't know the internal but usually databases are faster if they allow you to insert data in batches ¯\_(ツ)_/¯